# Modern View - DispForm

Tags: modern-experience

We just moved to O365 SharePoint and are having some growing pains.  A user just pointed out that when they go to the dispform for a list item in a modern list, the "created by/modified by" information doesn't appear on the form.  Switching the list to classic fixed this, but was wondering if there is a workaround that would show this info by default in the modern view?

Comment: Better place to ask is Microsofts own forum: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/bd-p/SharePointDev

Comment: Danny, good idea

Comment: @S.Hendricks: Did you ever find an answer?