# Modern List not showing Created Date

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

A list our Customer Service team uses to track orders used to show the Created Data and who created it when you clicked on the Item in Classic Version, but now in the Modern Experience they are not there. They are displayed as columns, so is there a way to add them in to the Item form?

Comment: same as https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203703/modern-view-dispform - no answer there, either..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's currently possible in modern.
You can view the dates in the table and in the "details" tab, but not on the "edit" tab.